k3s failed to prepare extraction snapshot
I've had a server crash while importing a large tarball with k3s ctr images import my_image.tar. After I restarted the server and tried to re-import it, I get:
unpacking docker.io/library/my_image (sha256:b69c6d6ebdb9517f7a93deede3ccf6380aebbc6a8fa68da14ab06bc1be131423)...ctr: failed to prepare extraction snapshot "extract-774071004-6PJT sha256:6e98c2a3f1228e003bc43b054a526b4bf36783f2ff04b8b6ce12b0beb640555d": failed to stat parent: stat /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/327/fs: no such file or directory: unknown

Directory 327 is missing. If I run k3s ctr snapshots tree it shows:
...
\_ sha256:594fd317ce6c40c5675454df43ad62b3a50115eb90ab7c9a15f1a4cb6f1115ed
 \_ sha256:89d2814f8e8a9fb32c126c93e86bc86984ef3483a65d5a53141d56f80bcc12fe
  \_ extract-662974335-9mi3 sha256:6e98c2a3f1228e003bc43b054a526b4bf36783f2ff04b8b6ce12b0beb640555d

I tried deleting the last two snapshots:
# k3s ctr snapshots delete sha256:6e98c2a3f1228e003bc43b054a526b4bf36783f2ff04b8b6ce12b0beb640555d
ctr: failed to remove "sha256:6e98c2a3f1228e003bc43b054a526b4bf36783f2ff04b8b6ce12b0beb640555d": snapshot sha256:6e98c2a3f1228e003bc43b054a526b4bf36783f2ff04b8b6ce12b0beb640555d does not exist: not found

# k3s ctr snapshots delete sha256:89d2814f8e8a9fb32c126c93e86bc86984ef3483a65d5a53141d56f80bcc12fe --force
ctr: failed to remove "sha256:89d2814f8e8a9fb32c126c93e86bc86984ef3483a65d5a53141d56f80bcc12fe": cannot remove snapshot with child: failed precondition

I've tried pruning the images with k3s ctr images prune --all but that didn't help. Is there a way to fix this without re-installing containerd?
UPDATE
After I've deleted /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd directory and re-imported all images, it fixed the issue.
